# how to add scripts to a button in filemaker pro

Tags: button, scripting, filemaker

I am using filemaker pro 16. I have written a script through manage scripts , add new script etc. How can I add or integrate that script to any button on the layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new button or choose any layout object and select Button from the Format Menu. 
Select the script you want at the bottom of the Button setup dialog.